# Not able to catch Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, signalr

Here is my code:

```
        public async Task ConnectToHub()
        {
            try
            {
                hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                                        .WithUrl(ApplicationConstants.ChutHubUrl)
                                        .Build();
                await hubConnection.StartAsync(); 
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                //I never enter this catch block (I set a breakpoint here 
                //but the debugger never breaks here).   
                //Instead, the app crashes and I get an unhandled HttpRequestException
            }
        }
```

At some point an HttpRequestException is thrown when `hubConnection.StartAsync(`) fails. However I can't seem to catch this exception. I always end up getting an unhandled HttpRequestException.

Comment: How do you receive that exception? You are writing it to the Console, and `catch` doesn't mean the debugger won't break.

Comment: Yeah I am writing to console to see if i enter the catch block. The console never shows anything. I also tried setting a break point at the start of the catch block and it never breaks there. And I always get an Unhandled Exception error in visual studio

Comment: Clean and rebuild.

Comment: I tried that. Still cant catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

This is very logical, to not see anything, because there is **no console** connected with your running web application. Beside that you running that on an extra thread.

You are running on asp.net, that have no console output.

If you wish to debug something like this, use the [Debug.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.write?view=netcore-3.1)

`Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);`

and use a program like [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to read the results

Comment: Actually, the hubconnection I am trying to connect to is running on asp.net but the code I have here is from my Xamarin.forms app which uses Console.Writeline to write to console. Sorry i shouldnt have included asp.net in the tags

Comment: So could the problem be that the exception is thrown in another thread meaning I cant catch it in the thread where I am calling hubConnection.StartAsync()?

Comment: @mbisonplayer probably yes - try the `Debug.Write` to see if you read it

Comment: Debug.Write does not read it. I also tried setting a breakpoint in the catchblock, but the debugger never breaks there

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my problem was. I had another *await hubConnection.StartAsync()* in some other method and it was the one that was actually throwing the HttpRequestException, but i didnt make a catch block to catch it. Thus the unhandled exception.